# RxJS mergeMap doesn't behave as expected

Tags: rxjs

I have this piece of RxJS code

```
this.listItems$ = this.store.select(EntityState.relationshipItems).pipe(
  map(fn => fn(12)),
  mergeMap(items => items),
  map(this.toListItem),
  toArray<ListItem>(),
  tap(x => console.log(x))
);
```

Using `mergeMap(items => items)` I'm trying to "flatten" the array, then `map` each item to another object, and then convert it back to an array.

However, the flow doesn't even reach the last `tap`. I can see the `toListItem` function is called, but I don't understand why it stops there.

---

Transforming it to

```
this.listItems$ = this.store.select(EntityState.relationshipItems).pipe(
  map(fn => fn(12)),
  map(items => items.map(this.toListItem)),
  tap(x => console.log(x))
);
```

makes it work, but I'd like to understand why the above one doesn't work.

Comment: If you want to learn more about mergeMap and other higher-order observables - take a look at my video course: https://www.packtpub.com/web-development/hands-rxjs-web-development-video

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `this.store.select(...)` is a Subject that never completes (if it did then you could select data just once which doesn't make sense).

However, `toArray` collects all emissions from its source and when its source completes it emits a single array. But the source is `this.store.select(...)` that never completes so `toArray` never emits anything.

So probably the easiest workaround would be just restructuring your chain:

```
this.listItems$ = this.store.select(EntityState.relationshipItems).pipe(
  map(fn => fn(12)),
  mergeMap(items => from(items).pipe(
    map(this.toListItem),
    toArray<ListItem>(),
    tap(x => console.log(x))
  )),
);
```

Now the source is `from` that completes after iterating `items` so `toArray` will receive complete notification and emit its content as well.

Comment: Thank you! That's what I was thinking too. Maybe the second way I posted in the question is the way to go? What do you think?

Comment: I think what you have is correct but it depends on what output you want from the chain.

Comment: I just need a transformed array as output. I wanted to try a fancier way using Rxjs and flattening the input array